# Uncaught reference error in simple onclick function

Tags: jquery

I wrote this jQuery code:

```
<script>
$(".text").click(function() {
$("#Content").html($(this).next(".text1").html());
});
</script>
```

But I did something wrong, I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined 15:16618
(anonymous function)
```

I have really no clue how to solve it! Please inform me if you need my html thanks!

---

**UPDATE:**

Somehow my code only works when the `class="text"` is wrapped into an `p`-tag:

```
<p class="text">
<a>B35.-Dermatophytose [Tinea]</a><a class="hidden id_code">587</a>
</p>
<div class="text1" style="display: none">
<p class="text">
<a class="num">B35.-</a><a class="bez">Tinea barbae</a>
<a class="hidden id_code">587</a>
<a class="hidden notation"></a>
<a class="hidden schlussel">j</a>
</p>
<p class="text">
........
```

When it's in the `a`-tag it wont work: What's going on?

```
<a class="text">B35.-Dermatophytose [Tinea]</a>
```

What do I have to change?

Comment: Do you have jQuery loaded? You need to load/include the jQuery `.js` library file.

Comment: @Sergio is right, you need to be sure that the Jquery library is loaded, and also sometimes it can take a while to be loaded, so the best option add the click handler it will be wrapped on a $(document).ready function, like: 

<script>
$(document).ready( function(){
    $(".text").click(function() {
       $("#Content").html($(this).next(".text1").html());
    });
});
</script>

Comment: Can you post your script references? If your able to bind that anonymous function wtih $(x).click() and not reference $ when the function is called then something must be happening between the two. Can you recreate this on jsbin.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your page, inside the `<head>` tags:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If the `$` is not defined I suspect jQuery's library is not loaded, this file will do that.

**Another problem you might have** is that the script you posted has to be after the html it refers to. Otherwise the code might give a error because it refers to html that is not there (yet).

You can wrap you code in a DOM ready function like: `$(document).ready(function(){ ...your code... });`

Or put your script code in the very bottom of the page, just before the `</body>` tag (end of the body).

Keep in mind that if you have other `.js` files that needs jQuery: that jQuery should be loaded before them.

Comment: Thanks youre absolutley right! In my new rail project i omitted it! But it is still not workin ghow i want it to! Maybe you can check my update?

Comment: @JohnSmith, did you check the second part of my answer? about wrapping the code in a ready function or moving it to the end of the html?

Comment: aha, got the answer as accepted. Thanks! but did you get it working?

Comment: Yes but only when i wrap the class 'text' into an p-tag!

Comment: @JohnSmith, saw your update now, but don't understand how it could be a problem. Do you mean you have `<a class="text"><a>B35.-Dermatophytose [Tinea]</a></a>` ? that would be invalid html (link inside link). Otherwise try to reproduce the problem here:  http://jsfiddle.net/JuNsQ/

Comment: I dont want the p-tag!

Comment: @JohnSmith, well like you did, or with `<div class="text">` for example. Or just with 1 `<a>` tag...